# How to crawl specific data from a website using stormcrawler

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, data-extraction, stormcrawler

I am crawling news websites using stormcrawler(v 1.16) and storing data on Elasticsearch (v 7.5.0). My crawler-conf file is as [stormcrawler files](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/elasticsearch/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources).I am using kibana for visualization.My issues are

- While crawling news website I want only urls of article content but i am also getting urls of ads,other tabs on website.What and where i have to make changes
  [Kibana link](http://3.85.218.169:5601)
- if i have to get only specific things from a URL(like only title or only content) how can we do that.

EDIT:
I was thinking to add a field in content index. So i made changes in src/main/resources/parsefilter.json ,ES_IndecInit.sh,and Crawler-conf.yaml. XPATH which i have added is correct . I have added as

`"parse.pubDate":"//META[@itemprop=\"datePublished\"]/@content"`

in parsefilter.

`parse.pubDate =PublishDate`

in crawler-conf and added

`PublishDate": {
        "type": "text",
        "index": false,
        "store": true}`

in properties of ES_IndexInit.sh . But still I am not getting any field named PublishDate in kibana or elasticsearch. 
ES_IndexInit.sh mapping is as folows:

```html
{
  "mapping": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
      "PublishDate": {
        "type": "text",
        "index": false,
        "store": true
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "store": true
      },
      "domain": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "host": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "store": true
      },
      "keywords": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "store": true
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "store": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Blackhawk. You could edit your question and add to it what you've just added in comment. This way everyone will see it right away... :). Kibana link currently seems to be broken.

Comment: JSoupParserBolt extracts URLs from page. You may filter URLs found on fetched webpage, using https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/URLFilters

Comment: hi Blackhawk, did you got the content. I also stuck in the same, how to create a custom class, how to use it, why the content in the website we given in seeds.txt is not coming in elastic.
or
how to store the content in a file without any elastic or any other technology.
can somebody post a custom scraper with a storm crawler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to indexing only news pages from a site is to rely on sitemaps, but not all sites will provide these.

Alternatively, you'd need a mechanism as part of the parsing, maybe in a ParseFilter, to determine that a page is a news item and filter based on the presence of a key / value in the metadata during the indexing.

The way it is done in the [news crawl dataset from CommonCrawl](https://github.com/commoncrawl/news-crawl) is that the seed URLs are sitemaps or RSS feeds.

To **not** index the content, simply comment out

```
  indexer.text.fieldname: "content"
```

in the configuration.